# Cutting short on the social login flow

Tags: oauth

**Note**: This is the first time I'm trying to implement a social login API, so thanks for bearing with me and helping me out!

I am developing a web application and I have a login and registration system already developed. Now, I am thinking of adding Facebook and Google+ login - with a backend. I went through their docs and other tutorials and they require to implement considerably a lot of things.

But, since I have a registration system already, I thought of doing something like this:

1. Have the social login buttons on the login page.
2. When the user clicks on a social login button and authorizes the app, the user data is returned from Google+, for example.
3. Now, instead of proceeding with the OAuth procedure like getting the user ID, secret ID and contacting their server from my server for token verification and getting data, is it possible to just use the data returned (after the user authorizes) and do the normal registration with the registration system that I already have?

These are the advantages that I see in doing this:

1. No need of extra code or database fields like token ID, etc.
2. User can add a password to their account whenever they want and login to the site or access their account by logging in through Facebook or Google+ given that they use the same email ID.
3. It's enough to use the social login providers' API once - the first time the user logs in (which technically registers the user to the site).

I know the advantages are the same when following the full OAuth2 implementation, but what difference does it make?

Now my questions are:

1. Is it OK to cut short on the social login as mentioned above?
2. Will I be losing any obvious advantage doing so (given that I already have a registration system in place)?
3. If yes, is anyone else cutting short on the flow in their website?

Comment: If you give me your backend lang, I could give you more details.

Comment: @khrm If that helps, I'm using Python.

Comment: OK. Then in python library you don't need to write verification code. It will automatically verify by parsing token for google+. Will check about facebook.

Comment: But you need to check aud.

Comment: "aud" is the client for which google created the token

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library Check here.

Comment: @khrm Sure. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system proposed by you has certain flaws, especially security related flaw. I would give you to the point answer:

> You will send data from client after getting it from google+ or other provider and use your registration process implicitly.

This approach is wrong as I myself as an attacker can send you the data from google+ using my clientid for an app. Will you register or login using the info I am sending? I can pretend to be anyone in your system if you do that.

> 1. Is it OK to cut short on the social login as mentioned above?
> 2. Will I be losing any obvious advantage doing so (given that I already have a registration system in place)?
> 3. If yes, is anyone else cutting short on the flow in their website?

1. No. (see the reason above).
2. No. You won't be losing advantage as you already have system in place. Most of the sites have a system in place for normal registration. They give oauth login by leveraging it. Some will say that the password is cumbersome or such, but all famous sites provide login and password including SO.

Now the question comes, how to simplify the oauth system given that you already have a system in place.

I recommend this(I would assume Google as a provider) flow with things starting with dot are what you need to do:

1. - You have a Google login button.
2. User click on Google Button.
3. The User is redirected to the Google site.
4. The user gives you permission.
5. Google redirects and give you a token.
6. - You can now send info and token to your server. (You need to send only token as backend will get info. Otherwise, a user with valid google+ token for your website can send you any info).
7. - Backend verify token and match that "aud" is equal to your client id. Or it can happen via a library. You will need to give only your client id.
8. - Backend get profile info from token in case of Google+(Name, email) while verifying which you can store as part of your registration process or login process if that email already exists.  You can store google id of user also. This is useful as some provider like fb don't always provide email for every account. (For some fb don't give email but for majority of cases it give you the email.)
9. - Backend send back session info or jwt token or any other time bounded process which tells that the user is login.

Your user can login via email also. If he isn't already registered then, then he will need to register. Otherwise, using forget, he can set password or from accounts settings he can set password.

You also need to be careful if the same user is connecting via a different provider, he need to have the same account in your system which you can handle via email.

Answer (score 4):

Kevin,

Authentication is a complex procedure involving lot of measures to ensure security. Hence Web-application/ App developers, delegate this critical piece of work to Identity providers like Google, Microsoft, Facebook etc. These Identity providers are trusted by the app developers and more importantly the consumers trust them too.

Why do app developers provide third party/ social logins? Because, it gives the users of the app some advantages.

1. They don't have to create new account with the app and remember the new set of credentials. Instead they can use the same credentials they are using with the Identity provider, to gain access to the app. This is huge.
2. They don't have to trust the app completely, means how the sensitive information like passwords, security questions are handled in the app, as they are not providing any sensitive information directly on the app. Only needed public information is fed to the app from the Identity provider. This is huge too.
3. No need to worry about the system compromise and leak of sensitive information as all Open ID providers have better security policies in place. This gives consumers a high degree of confidence when using your system through third party logins.

> "All the advantages you mentioned will be great for the app developers
>   at the cost of disadvantages to the consumers of the app."

Lets put the consumer disadvantages on the side and look at the advantages you mentioned:

**No need of extra code or database fields like token ID, etc.**

You still need code/setup to validate your own tokens. You have to add more logic to verify the external tokens, but the consumers will have the advantage of using the external providers like they are in any other application.

**User can add a password to their account whenever they want and login to the site or access their account by logging in through Facebook or Google+ given that they use the same email ID.**

This is little confusing as users may choose external provider, so they don't have to remember a new password. Also, the account validation process is different if you use external login vs id/password login. If you are willing to provide both, then you already have the system in place, to verify the account for external logins. Then your first advantage is void and you are better of using Open ID spec.

**It's enough to use the social login providers' API once - the first time the user logs in (which technically registers the user to the site).**

This approach adds confusion to the flow for consumers. They expect to see a login screen from third party provider for authentication (when they click on google+ or FB), but instead they see your login screen.

Instead of cut short approach, it would be worth to use the complete flow. You might add more logic to handle the token verification with external providers, but, actual complex logic of token validation is delegated to the external providers. This adds no confusion to the end user and they can trust your application easily through social id providers. Even though, users can authenticate through social Id providers, it is always a best practice to have the profile object of that user in your system (without the sensitive information like password).

Since you have your own registration process in place, this may not be a huge advantage. But, please look into the open source implementation of any of the Security Token Service (STS) providers, to see if you can borrow some of the features for validation external providers.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you,
Soma.